# Integrate a specific font with Android apk

Tags: android, fonts, apk

I have built an application which displays the news in Nepali (Devnagari) font.
Everything is fine but the problem is that the font is not displayed properly in some Android phones.

Here I have posted two images showing the variation of the same content in different phones. The first one is perfect but the second one is incorrectly displayed.

1st Image with correct fonts

[image: 1st Image with correct fonts]

2nd Image with incorrect fonts

[image: 2nd Image with incorrect fonts]

The problem I realized is that the second phone does not contained the correct font installed in it.
How can we get rid of this problem?

I have got no proper idea regarding this, but a solution that came in my mind is that - What if we integrate the necessary font along with the apk file and the font too gets downloaded with the apk.

Please pass me suggestion for this and would be grateful to know how to implement any solution that exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the native Android Textview Component you could use the method:

```
public void setTypeface (Typeface tf)
```

And create the typeface this way :

```
static Typeface  createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)
Create a new typeface from the specified font data.

Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssetManager(),"RELATIVE_PATH_TO_YOUR_TYPFACE_IN_THE_ASSET_FOLDER");
```

If you are using Android Studio the asset folder should be created under src/main/assets.

Answer (score 1):

Make 1 folder in assets named "fonts", put your font files inside that folder. e.g. see following image

[image]

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

Then declare Typeface object

```
Typeface allFontType, allFontTypeNormal, allFontTypeLight;

try 
{
    allFontType         = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Dosis-Bold.ttf");
    allFontTypeNormal   = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Dosis-Medium.ttf");
    allFontTypeLight    = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Dosis-ExtraLight.ttf");
}
catch (Exception e1) 
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
    allFontType         =  Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    allFontTypeNormal   =  Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
    allFontTypeLight    =  Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

To apply font in TextView use following code

```
TextView lblDaysName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblDaysName);
lblDaysName.setTypeface(allFontTypeNormal);
```